# addClass to <img> inside <a>

Tags: javascript

On my website, users click on an image. However, in the code they're actually clicking on an `<a>` with an `<img>` in it. I want there to appear a red ring around the image when the user clicks it. The `<img>` and the `<a>` have the same id and class.

Is it possible to have `$(this).addClass('SelectedService');` add a class to an `<img>` inside an `<a>`?

Comment: HTML elements can't have same id.

Comment: @aksU: shell not have ;)

Comment: you can't have same id in one page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to go for the jquery use css

Your html

```
<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg"/>
```

and css

```
img:active
{
    border:3px solid red;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPYYu/)**

Checkout upper link for the demo

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ahref1').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).find('img').first().addClass("SelectedService");
});
```

If your html is something like:

```
<a id="ahref1" href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript.  If you just want to change the style once an anchor tag is clicked, you can use the pseudo-class `:active`.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LW9y6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
$('#id_link').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('SelectedService');
});
```

assuming that class is a red ring

Answer (score -1):

Instead of selecting `$(this)`, you should use like this to work.

```
$('img').addClass('SelectedService');
```

this will select `img` tag inside `a` tag and add class to `img`

Comment: you should add a click event to your 'a' tag. Like $('a').click(function() {$('img').addClass('SelectedService');});